# Popover is disappearing while trying to show it for the second time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a popover icon and 2 radio buttons (yes and no).

I wrote code to show popover data-content text when user clicks on yes and hide data-content text when user clicks on no.

I am showing popover content when user clicks on yes using
$('#element').popover('show');

I am hiding popover content when user clicks on no using
$('#element').popover('hide');

Popover text is showing as expected when user clicks on yes radio button for the first time.
After that when clicks on no radio button and again click on yes radio button then popover text is disappearing within a fraction of second and user doesn't have enough time to read the content present in the popover.

Please help

Comment: please show me the code you wrote, so I can know which part requires correction or addition

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution**

```
<div class="container">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Some content inside the popover">popover</a><br />
          <input type="radio" id="answer" name="answer" value="yes"/> Yes
          <input type="radio" id="answer" name="answer" value="no"/> No
        </div>
        
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[type=radio][name=answer]").on('change', function() {
                var radioVal = $(this).val()
                if(radioVal=='yes') {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show')
                } else if(radioVal=='no') {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide')
                }
            })
        });
        </script>
```